# Removing repetition and clustered similarity from randomness

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to generate dynamic questions for a math quiz website.

Here's a contrived example of the code I have:

```
from random import randint                                            

def get_simple_addition_question():                                   
    question_text = "What is %s + %s?"                                
    question_args = (randint(2,10), randint(2,10))                     
    return question_text % question_args
```

When I generate a list from this dynamic question generator, I sometimes see questions repeated, or groupings of  similar questions.  I know this is to be expected due to the nature of randonimity, but I'm seeking a way to prevent it.

The dynamic question definitions are stored in a DB and can be updated through an admin interface.  Therefore I'm adding a validator to the model for dynamic questions so that questions that can't be used to generate sufficiently unique lists aren't accepted.

What are the best approaches to ensure that identical questions are never successive, and how can I prevent grouping of similar questions whilst maintaining seemingly random question generation?

Currently investigating difflib, specifically SequenceMatcher's .ratio() method, I'll update if I get anywhere.

I'm not necessarily looking for code, just re-assurance I'm on the right path in my quest to remove repetition and similarity clustering.

Comment: What do you mean by "similar questions"?

Answer (score 1):

The standard library (in most languages) is a poor source of randomness.
The same holds for OS function calls, which are used by the above.
I imagine you could spend a few more CPU cycles on this, so I suggest using some cryptographic hash function or block/stream cipher.
For example, DES or SHA.
Of course you should use the standard implementation of such - there are many in all languages.
Give it some string as an input, e.g. (current time || machine IP), whatever.
And - viola - you get your result.
Don't forget that in small ranges (e.g. [1-10]) repetition is unavoidable (e.g., once in 10 trials). Or I got you wrong and this is what all your question is about?

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

So, say you have 10 questions and you need 20 unique numbers:

```
random.sample(range(0,100),20)
```